# Why my IF function doesn't bring all the values in the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a file where i take values from some sheet in that file based on ID. 
These are the Sheets that i am working on in my workbook.
This is my **Preferences** sheet: [image]
and i put values from **Preference** sheet to the **Main** sheet.
[image]

I used this formula in **Main** sheet to take the values from **Preference** sheet :
`=IF(A2=References!A2;References!F2;IF(References!F2 = 0;C2;References!F2 ))`which works perfectly fine for some values unless the **ID** has a *Symbol* or a *Letter* in the end.

I did some Research on Internet but i could not find anything useful.
Thank you.

Comment: Either the A column cell in your references or in your main sheet would have extra unseen characters that will return a `FALSE` in your `IF` statement. Trailing spaces maybe?

Comment: What is the cell format of column A in `Preferences` sheet and column A in `Main` sheet?

Comment: @JvdV there are no emtpy spaces,

Comment: @Justyna MK both of them are in _General_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess i complicated more that i should have. 
I used this Code and i fixed it `=IF(References!F2="";SSL_List!C2;References!F2)`
now it gives all the values.